# How to retrieve rows that begin and end with specific characters?

Tags: sql, select, sql-like

I have one table called STUDENT. In this table there are two columns, ID and NAME. I want to retrieve all rows from this table where name starts with 'ab' and ends with 'k'. What is the SQL query for doing this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM STUDENT WHERE NAME LIKE 'ab%k';
```

For **wildcard operations** you should use a `WHERE` clause with the [LIKE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_%28SQL%29#LIKE) keyword that allows you to **filter columns that match a given pattern** using the `%`symbol as a wildcard.

There is a question about the [List of special characters for SQL LIKE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712580/list-of-special-characters-for-sql-like-clause) that has a good list of `LIKE` *special characters*

Answer (score 3):

its like if you are looking for find name start with H and end with F just write query.

```
select emp_name from employee_test where emp_name like 'H%F';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select ID, Name from student where name like 'ab%%k'
```