# Why is the T-SQL "LIKE" operator not evaluating this expression like I think it should?

Tags: t-sql, syntax, sql-like, startswith

I am attempting to error trap a T-SQL variable name by making sure that the value of the variable is prefixed with a bracket "[".

Here's an example of how I am trying to do this:

```
DECLARE @thing nvarchar(20)
SET @thing = '[55555'
IF(@thing NOT LIKE '[' + '%') --If the value does not start with [ then add it
BEGIN
SET @thing = '[' + @thing
END
PRINT @thing
```

The example above PRINT's `[[55555`

Notice that the original value of @thing was prefixed with the bracket "[". I was expecting the IF condition would have returned false since `"[55555" is LIKE '[' + '%'`

Why is the IF condition not returning false? And, more importantly I suppose, what is the correct syntax to check for the existence of a string that occurs at the beginning of a variable string value?

**EDIT**
It appears as there is something special about the bracket "[". When I run LIKE on a bracket it doesn't do what I expect, but when I don't use a bracket the LIKE works the way I expect.

Check out these examples:

```
IF('[' NOT LIKE '[')
BEGIN
PRINT '[ is NOT LIKE ['
END
ELSE
BEGIN
PRINT '[ is LIKE ['
END

IF('StackO' NOT LIKE 'StackO')
BEGIN
PRINT 'STACKO is NOT LIKE StackO'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
PRINT 'STACKO is LIKE StackO'
END
```

Here's the output of the two conditions:

> [ is NOT LIKE [
>
> STACKO is LIKE StackO

Comment: Any difference if using `'[%'` and not the form with concatenation?

Comment: No. No difference. Actually, on my first attempt I used your version. In trying different syntax's I forgot to move it back to the og '[%' prior to posting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it may be because '[' is actually part of the LIKE operators syntax, as defined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

You need to define an escape character to escape the [, like this:

```
DECLARE @thing nvarchar(20)
SET @thing = '[55555'
IF(@thing NOT LIKE '\[%' ESCAPE '\' )
BEGIN
SET @thing = '[' + @thing
END
PRINT @thing
```

An alternative solution would be the following:

```
DECLARE @thing nvarchar(20)
SET @thing = '[55555'
IF(LEFT(@thing,1) <> '[') --If the value does not start with [ then add it
BEGIN
SET @thing = '[' + @thing
END
PRINT @thing
```

Answer (score 2):

To get it working change your check to

```
IF (SUBSTRING(@thing, 1,1) != '[')
```

The reason why the like is not working is because [ is a special char in like. just like % is. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712580/list-of-special-characters-for-sql-like-clause)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - You'll notice you all had the same principled answer and since I could only pick one, I randomly chose Tom.

Answer (score 2):

Bracket characters (`[` and `]`) [are special wildcard characters in T-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx). To search for those literal characters, you'll want to escape those characters (indicate that you want to search for those literal characters, rather than employing them as wildcards). Use `ESCAPE` to do this, like so:

```
DECLARE @thing nvarchar(20)
SET @thing = '[55555'
-- pick an escape character you won't see in your content
IF(@thing NOT LIKE '![' + '%' ESCAPE '!')
BEGIN
  SET @thing = '[' + @thing
END
PRINT @thing
```

This prints `[55555`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx):

> You can search for character strings that include one or more of the special wildcard characters... To search for the percent sign as a character instead of as a wildcard character, the ESCAPE keyword and escape character must be provided. For example, a sample database contains a column named `comment` that contains the text `30%`. To search for any rows that contain the string `30%` anywhere in the `comment` column, specify a WHERE clause such as `WHERE comment LIKE '%30!%%' ESCAPE '!'`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - You'll notice you all had the same principled answer and since I could only pick one, I randomly chose Tom.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape special characters (brackets, single quotes, etc.).  In this case, you could do this:

```
LIKE '[['
```

EDIT:

PS -- [ is a special character because it can be used for wildcards, like this: `LIKE '[0-9]'` to do pattern-matching.  (In this case, the match is like a regex -- any digit between 0 and 9.