# SQL 'LIKE' query using '%' where the search criteria contains '%'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I have an SQL query as below.

```
Select * from table 
where name like '%' + search_criteria + '%'
```

If search_criteria = 'abc', it will return data containing `xxxabcxxxx` which is fine.

But if my search_criteria = 'abc%', it will still return data containing `xxxabcxxx`, which should not be the case.

How do I handle this situation?

Comment: then why add your own %?

Comment: how to do it depends on your engine, but obviously you have to escape your own %

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: Use the MATCH instead of LIKE.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you want a `%` symbol in `search_criteria` to be treated as a literal character rather than as a wildcard, escape it to `[%]`

```
... where name like '%' + replace(search_criteria, '%', '[%]') + '%'
```

Comment: thank you, gives column with % sign `select  * from tablename where Column like '%[%]%'`

Answer (score 15):

Use an escape clause:

```
select *
  from (select '123abc456' AS result from dual
        union all
        select '123abc%456' AS result from dual
       )
  WHERE result LIKE '%abc\%%' escape '\'
```

Result

```
123abc%456
```

You can set your escape character to whatever you want. In this case, the default '\'. The escaped '\%' becomes a literal, the second '%' is not escaped, so again wild card.

See [List of special characters for SQL LIKE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712580/list-of-special-characters-for-sql-like-clause)

Answer (score 12):

The easiest solution is to dispense with "like" altogether:

```
Select * 
from table
where charindex(search_criteria, name) > 0
```

I prefer charindex over like.  Historically, it had better performance, but I'm not sure if it makes much of difference now.

Comment: I really like this answer, as it is clearly not vulnerable to SQL Injection, as you've avoided the string concatenation.

Comment: check out [sql-server-performance](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/forum/threads/charindex-vs-like.16120/) for a v short comparison. Note that using `like 'findme%'` can still use an index if it exists.

Answer (score 6):

To escape a character in sql you can use `!`:

---

**EXAMPLE - USING ESCAPE CHARACTERS**

It is important to understand how to "Escape Characters" when pattern matching. These examples deal specifically with escaping characters in Oracle.

Let's say you wanted to search for a % or a _ character in the SQL LIKE condition. You can do this using an Escape character.

Please note that you can only define an escape character as a single character (length of 1).

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM suppliers
WHERE supplier_name LIKE '!%' escape '!';
```

This SQL LIKE condition example identifies the ! character as an escape character. This statement will return all suppliers whose name is %.

Here is another more complicated example using escape characters in the SQL LIKE condition.

```
SELECT *
FROM suppliers
WHERE supplier_name LIKE 'H%!%' escape '!';
```

This SQL LIKE condition example returns all suppliers whose name starts with H and ends in %. For example, it would return a value such as 'Hello%'.

You can also use the escape character with the _ character in the SQL LIKE condition.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM suppliers
WHERE supplier_name LIKE 'H%!_' escape '!';
```

This SQL LIKE condition example returns all suppliers whose name starts with H and ends in _ . For example, it would return a value such as 'Hello_'.

---

Reference: [sql/like](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from table where name like search_criteria
```

if you are expecting the user to add their own wildcards...

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape it: on many databases this is done by preceding it with backslash, `\%`.

So `abc` becomes `abc\%`.

Your programming language will have a database-specific function to do this for you. For example, [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) has mysql_escape_string() for the [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) database.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the percent sign `\%` to make it part of your comparison value.

Comment: This only works if you use the `ESCAPE` option of the `LIKE` operator. There is no default escape character (in SQL Server, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

May be this one help :)

```
DECLARE @SearchCriteria VARCHAR(25)
SET  @SearchCriteria = 'employee'
IF CHARINDEX('%', @SearchCriteria) = 0
BEGIN
SET @SearchCriteria = '%' + @SearchCriteria + '%'
END
SELECT * 
FROM Employee
WHERE Name LIKE @SearchCriteria
```