# search in a column having entries like `a%` as entry for a column

Tags: mysql

I want a query to return rows with the column having entries like following:

> abcda%aaa, pa%rdeep, sonisa%b etc.

Tried using following but doesn't get the desired results.

```
select * from table where column like "%a%%"
```

I want correct replacement for above so as to search for only those rows having `"a%"`  as an entry for the column in the table not those starting with a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table j1
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    thing varchar(100) not null
);

insert j1(thing) values ('abcda%aaa'),('fish'),('pa%rdeep'),('cat'),('sonisa%b'),('a'),('a\\%');


select * from j1 where thing like '%a\%%';
+----+-----------+
| id | thing     |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | abcda%aaa |
|  3 | pa%rdeep  |
|  5 | sonisa%b  |
+----+-----------+
```

Please see MySQL [String Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html)

Comment: Hi @Drew. Thanks for the reply. But my problem is that my values are not static meaning to say that I don't have a clue where to put percentage sign for solving this because data is coming from a variable and I only have the option to use the same variable in my java code by appending percent('%') symbol as var = "%"+var+"%" and var may be anything and  issue arises when`%` is present in the var itself

Comment: I thought you wanted stuff that had an embedded % like a% or jason%

Comment: actually var may be anything i.e the index of `%` cannot be guessed. so how come I use`\` before `%`

Comment: so if you have an embedded % like jason% and you want to find all that have jason%, then do the above with % + (your thing like jason%) + %

Comment: but focus on the slash escape sequence just after jason

Comment: I dont know at which index to use escape as var may b anything like aaa%a, or aaa% or %aa etc.

Comment: Actually, I a newbee at stackoverflow. Can I have your mail so that we can chat over there?

Comment: A more general solution could be `where thing like concat('%', replace('anyStringContaining%', '%', '\\%'), '%');`

Answer (score 2):

> If you want to escape `%` then You have to use **backslash `\`**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `column_name` LIKE '%a\%%'.
```

---

Reference

- [String Comparison Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator%5Flike)
- [SQL 'LIKE' query using '%' where the search criteria contains '%'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10803529/5019802)