# How to write the LIKE syntax where the search term includes a percentage (%)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I am using `SQL Server 2012` and I need to perform a search on a specific field, called `Notes`. The search criteria is to find all rows where the term `8%` is mentioned in that specific field.

The `WHERE` clause of my `T-SQL` query looks like this:

```
WHERE [Notes] like '%[8%]%'
```

However, the query is not filtering correctly based on the above syntax. It is also including rows where the term `8` is mentioned.

I had a look at the answers proposed in the question below, but they are still not giving me the correct answer.

[SQL 'LIKE' query using '%' where the search criteria contains '%'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803489/sql-like-query-using-where-the-search-criteria-contains)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single character class represents a single character.  So `[%]` means a literal percent symbol, and `8[%]` means literal `8%`.  Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE [Notes] like '%8[%]%'
```

### Demo

Comment: easy and simple ...:)

Answer (score 3):

you need to escape `%` in query for example below

```
SELECT columns FROM table
   WHERE column LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'
```

[Using SQL Escape Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-sql-escape-sequences)

Below is from MSDN

[Pattern Matching with the ESCAPE Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql)

You can search for character strings that include one or more of the special wildcard characters. For example, the discounts table in a customers database may store discount values that include a percent sign (%). To search for the percent sign as a character instead of as a wildcard character, the ESCAPE keyword and escape character must be provided. For example, a sample database contains a column named comment that contains the text 30%. To search for any rows that contain the string 30% anywhere in the comment column, specify a WHERE clause such as `WHERE comment LIKE '%30!%%' ESCAPE '!'`. If ESCAPE and the escape character are not specified, the Database Engine returns any rows with the string 30.

---

you can try below answer given by @TimBiegeleisen that is also easy way.

Answer (score 0):

just change your where clause as

```
WHERE `Notes` LIKE '%8!%%' ESCAPE '!
```