# Using like to query 100% key word in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

I am trying to query Keyword 100% using Like command.

```
LIKE (‘%100%%’)
```

But the command is querying for all keywords with `100` which is not what I
want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL 'LIKE' query using '%' where the search criteria contains '%'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803489/sql-like-query-using-where-the-search-criteria-contains)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Escape Character.
Try:

```
Select * from MyTable m where m.Column1 like '%100\%%' escape '\'
```

Escape Character can be set as per your convenience.

In the above query, replace MyTable with your table name and Column1 with your Column Name.

Answer (score 1):

You could also take advantage of SQL Server's `LIKE` operator's regex syntax, and use `[%]` to represent a literal percent:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE col LIKE '%100[%]%';
```

### Demo

I prefer this method to the accepted answer because it makes more explicit the intention to represent a literal character, and it avoids the possible need for an `ESCAPE` clause.