# SQL SELECT where column CONTAINS substring

Tags: sql

I have a database containing all usernames. Now, I have a page where I can search for an user. At the moment I use the following SQL:

```
SELECT uid, username, id, status 
FROM users 
WHERE `username` LIKE <search string>
```

Now, I have a record with the username `Hattorius`. But when I use that SQL syntax, and search for `hatt`. It doesn't give any results. How can I still make this work?

I searched some around, but nobody really had an answer to this.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is using non-standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: Column collation? Did you forget the `%` wildcards?

Comment: use %<search string>%

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL 'LIKE' query using '%' where the search criteria contains '%'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803489/sql-like-query-using-where-the-search-criteria-contains)

Comment: Is your real problem that it doesn't find the upper-case H when you search for lower-case h? Hattorius vs hattorius? If so you can either store a lower-case version of the name for searches (portable but duplicates data) or you can convert both values to lower-case when you search (probably not portable). For example "where lower(username) like lower(<search string>)".

Answer (score 7):

Try to use `LIKE` :

```
SELECT uid, username, id, status 
FROM users 
WHERE `username` LIKE '%hatt%'
```

Answer (score 5):

Remove the single quotes:

```
SELECT uid, username, id, status 
FROM users 
WHERE username LIKE '%hatt%'
```