# How to write a SQL query to find values which contain '%' symbol?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause, sql-like

Value is a string which contains *alphanumeric characters and special characters* also. And I am trying to display values which contains **'%'**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL 'LIKE' query using '%' where the search criteria contains '%'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803489/sql-like-query-using-where-the-search-criteria-contains)

Comment: With the duplicate, for standard SQL solutions (instead of SQL Server specific solutions), look at - for example - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10803697/466862).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use string functions:

```
select val from mytable where locate(val, '%')
```

If you want to do this with `like`, you need the `escape` option:

```
select val from mytable where val like '%|%%' escape '|';
```

Comment: select val from mytable where val like '%|%%' escape '|';  Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another way (though perhaps not faster):

```
WHERE val REGEXP('%')
```