# Wildcards as values in like operator return all data from the particular table. like '%%%%'

Tags: coldfusion

Generally we are doing a search operation by using **like operator** in sql. 
For example,

If user doing search text ( input string ) as "Kannan" means It's should work operation like

```
Select * from users where name like <cfqueryparam value="%#url.search#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
```

The above cfm query should be like ( **Select * from users where name like '%Kannan%'** )

One of my end user **search text ( input string ) is %%%** means  So the query like

Select * from users where name like '%%%%%'

It's return all the records from the user table. I don't have any name contains % But the search string (%%%) return all the records.

I've directly run the select * from users where name like '%%%%%' in my sql it's also return all records from the table.

I've go through the docs they mentioned as like '%%%' (or) like '%%%%' ( or ) if the % only in between start & end % (wildcards ) symbol without any other string mean it's return all the records from the particular table.

How I can handle this problem ? If the user search %%% then should not return any records until the name column having % value

Thanks is advance !

Comment: `%` is a wildcard. a clause like `'%%%'` is simply 3 wildcards. If you need need to look for the `%` (or other reserved) character, you need to enclose it (the character) in brackets (`[]`). Therefore `WHERE Column LIKE '%[%]%'` would search for values that contain the character `'%'`.

Comment: Lamu, Thank you for your attention here. % is an user string so we can't give [] for all values. Because the user string is dynamic one. Consider my first example if the user search as 'Kannan' means then it's consider as  LIKE '%[kannan]%'. it's not return any records. Hope you understand !

Comment: @Kannan.P, you will need to escape wildcard characters in the user input. Not just "%', but "_" and square brackets as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551891/t-sql-special-characters-to-escape-for-like-operator-wildcard-search

Comment: @DanGuzman,Let's imagine if the column have value with % for example ( Hai%how ). How you use this in like operator. Could you please give your sample query ?

Comment: The resultant query would need to be `LIKE '%Hai[%]how%'` or `LIKE '%' + 'Hai[%]how' + '%'`

Comment: @DanGuzman Again I want to remind one thing my input is dynamic one. So I can't use [] in specific place. As well if my column have % value mean that time I should consider that too. So I can't omit anything .

Comment: @Kannan.P Mostly the search text shouldn't be only the % symbol. But the search text contains with some other alpha numeric value. for example user can using the search text 100%. So, the question is valid one.

Comment: Thank you for understood  Sathis. But the testing/QA time  it's get failed because they test it bu using %%% value. In that time it's return all records from the particular table. So If we have % in our combination of string mean the we should consider that. I hope understood you know the logic in CFML side too

Comment: @Kannan.P Just try the script with escape clause `like '%!%%' ESCAPE '!';`

Comment: @Kannan.P, I understand the input is user-entered. The code will need to escape embedded wildcard characters so that those are not evaluated as wildcards in the resultant `LIKE` expression. The user does not need to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the literal % character:

```
Select * from users where name like <cfqueryparam value="%#Replace(url.search,"%","\%","all")#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
```

You may try like this for search scenario. Hope, it may help to you.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
Select * 
from users 
where name like <cfqueryparam value="%#url.search#%" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
```

to this:

```
<cfset searchString = "%" & replace(url.search, "%", "[%]", "all") & "%">
<cfquery name = "something">
Select * 
from users 
where name like <cfqueryparam value="#searchString#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">       
</cfquery>
```

Comment: I would add that another replace should be done for '_'. But, otherwise, this is spot on.

Answer (score 1):

In a `LIKE` pattern, the `'%'` matches any number of characters, including zero.

So, multiple `'%'` in a row *do exactly the same thing*.  They match any number of characters, including zero characters.

The other wildcard, `'_'` behaves differently.  It matches exactly one character -- not zero not two.  So `'__'` matches exactly two.  And `'__%'` matches a string with two or more characters.

EDIT:

If you want to search for the value explicitly, don't use `like`.

```
where instr(name, @uservalue)
```

Only use `like` if you want `%` and `_` to be treated as wildcards.  And, if you are thinking of allowing that, I would recommend regular expressions instead -- because they are more powerful and commonly used across many different systems (databases and otherwise).

Comment: please go through my issue again. In my case %%% user input. I can write as LIKE '%userInput%' , So here my user input is %%%. It's very rare case but it's an problem too.

Comment: @Kannan.P . . . What is your issue?  Do you actually want to search for percent signs?

Comment: Yes. If the column have Percent sign mean I should search , but if the column don't have any percent signs mean then it's should return o records instead of all .

Comment: @Kannan.P -  Take a look at Gordon's edit. If just you're searching for a *literal* anywhere within the text, just use `WHERE INSTR( column, '%') > 0`, instead of `LIKE`.  Essentially, it does the same thing as `LIKE`, but doesn't treat percent symbols`%`, etc... as wildcards.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6f00f6f9bb7e040a9566845c402dd7de

Answer (score 0):

At a total guess, but seems like you'll need to replace the characters in your parameter first, and then search:

```
SET @YourParameter = '%' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@YourParameter,'[','[[]'),'_','[_]'),'%','[%]') + '%';

SELECT {Your Columns}
FROM YourTable
WHERE YourColumn LIKE @YourParameter;
```

Comment: @lamu, if I follow your method as replace a means, Imagine  in my name column really have value %, For example ( K%nnan) means that time it's should return result. But your replace case omit the % as ( Knnan ) and return no records. I hope you understood the scenario.

Comment: In your example, square bracket should be replaced first (you add some when replacing % and _).

Comment: @Kannan.P `'K%nnan' LIKE '%[%]%'` is true, `'Kannan' LIKE '%[%]%'` is false.

Comment: You're right, @SalmanA, I added `[` as an after thought and simply didn't consider the order.

Comment: Why would this omit the `'%'` @Kannan.P? And it's `rn`; it's not an `m`...

Answer (score 0):

Mostly the search text shouldn't be only the % symbol. But the search text contains with some other alpha numeric value. for example user can using the search text 100%. So, the question is valid one. Here I would suggest you to use the Escape clause.

The given following SQL statement, the ESCAPE clause used to escape the character ! to negate the meaning of ‘%’ to find the string ‘100% Free’ in the column offer of the product table.

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE offer LIKE '%100!% Free%' ESCAPE '!';
```

You may try with that in your search scenario. Hope, it may help to you.

Source from Using SQL LIKE with the ESCAPE clause here https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-the-sql-like-operator/