# Regular expression in PostgreSQL LIKE clause

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, pattern-matching

I'm stuck with a simple regular expression. Not sure what I'm missing. A little rusty on regex skills.

The expression I'm trying to match is:

```
select * from table where value like '00[1-9]%'
-- (third character should not be 0)
```

So this should match `'0090D0DF143A'` (format: text) but it's NOT!

Comment: The SQL `LIKE` operator does not support regular expression. You need to use `similar to` or the `~` operator: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Like [@a_horse commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24368404/regular-expression-in-postgresql-like-clause#comment37682867_24368404), you would have to use the [regular expression operator `~`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) to use [bracket expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ATOMS-TABLE).
But there's more. I suggest:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  value ~ '^00[^0]'
```

`^` ... match at start of string (your original expression could match at *any* position).
`[^0]` ... a bracket expression (character class) matching *any* character that is not `0`.

Or **better**, yet:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  value LIKE '00%'       -- starting with '00'
AND    value NOT LIKE '000%'  -- third character is not '0'
```

Why? `LIKE` is not as powerful, but typically faster than regular expressions. It's probably substantially faster to narrow down the set of candidates with a cheap `LIKE` expression.

Generally, you would use `NOT LIKE '__0'`, but since we already establish `LIKE '00%'` in the other predicate, we can use the narrower (cheaper) pattern `NOT LIKE '000'`.

Postgres can use a simple btree **index** for the left-anchored expressions `value LIKE '00%'` (important for big tables), while that might not work for a more complex regular expression. The latest version of Postgres can use indexes for simple regular expressions, so it *might* work for this example. Details:

- [Difference between LIKE and ~ in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452395/difference-between-like-and-in-postgres/12459689#12459689)

Comment: Maybe `'^00[^0]'` or `'^00[^0].*'` instead of `'^00[^0]%'` in the first query? Otherwise it does not match the example `0090D0DF143A`

Comment: It does indeed use indexes for this regex, see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7019f/1

Comment: @NickBarnes: In this case, the first query is about as fast as the second. Without matching index, the second will be substantially faster. I tested, building on your fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d9b43/5 Performance tests on sqlfiddle are not always reliable. I ran the tests in a local 9.3 setup.

Comment: @Erwin Wow, quite a difference! I'll have to remember that one ;)

Answer (score 5):

PostgreSQL's `LIKE` operator doesn't support [*charlist*], however `SIMILAR TO` does.

check [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712580/list-of-special-characters-for-sql-like-clause) for a comprehensive list across DBs

Comment: That's not specific to Postgres. The SQL standard does not define any regex for the `LIKE` operator.

Comment: [Never use `SIMILAR TO`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452395/difference-between-like-and-in-postgres/12459689#12459689)

Comment: Why So @ErwinBrandstetter?

Comment: @borarak: I linked to my rationale.