# SQL - how to limit query with LIKE to select a certain number of digits after the %?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to parse model names from a table using `LIKE`. Each model value looks like `new_model_01215`, `new_model_01557` etc. Where `new_model_01` part will be the same for all values. And there will always be only 3 numbers after the 01.

I've created the following statement and it works almost as expected. But the problem is that it returns values having more than 5 digits in a postfix.

What should I change in the query to return values with no more than 3 digits after the 01%?

```
SELECT model_name FROM models_table WHERE model_name LIKE 'new_model_01%'
```

Comment: Sounds like a regex match would help.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24368404/regular-expression-in-postgresql-like-clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for that. In Postgres this can be done using [`~`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) or `similar to`:

```
SELECT model_name 
FROM models_table 
WHERE model_name ~ 'new_model_01[0-9]{3}'
```

Comment: I just saw somewhere around that its better to avoid usage of similar to

Answer (score 3):

In postgresql you can use the `_` (underscore) character to match a single character, so three in a row would match your strings:

```
    SELECT model_name FROM models_table WHERE model_name LIKE 'new_model_01___'
```

Comment: The underscore will match not only digits but any char.

Comment: @forpas, you are correct that the wildcard matches any single character, but matching only digits was not the issue for the OP - only matching a specific number of digits, so I suggested the wildcard as being more efficient for the task than using regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it

```
SELECT model_name 
FROM models_table 
WHERE LEFT(model_name,LEN(model_name)-3)='new_model_01'
```

Answer (score 0):

The curly brackets represents length of the input. Can use regex_matches(..) to match a regex

```
   SELECT model_name FROM 
    models_table WHERE 
   regexp_matches(model_name,  
   'new_model_01[0-9]{3}%') is not null
```

Comment: what does {10} mean?

Comment: curly brackets indicates no of digits or length

Comment: LIKE does not support regular expressions

Comment: umm.. never thought of `like` wouldnt support regular expressions as it supports wild card, patterns via `%`