# How ''~'' and ''^'' actually works with practical examples in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I'm trying to solve a case that, a lot of users have used the syntax that contains the "~".
As below:

```sql
select 
  business_postal_code as zip, 
  count(distinct case when left(business_address,1) ~ '^[0-9]' then lower(split_part(business_address, ' ', 2)) 
      else lower(split_part(business_address, ' ', 1)) end ) as n_street 
from sf_restaurant_health_violations
where business_postal_code is not null
group by 1
order by 2 desc, 1 asc;
```

link to acess the case: https://platform.stratascratch.com/coding/10182-number-of-streets-per-zip-code?python=

But I couldn't undernstand how this part of the code actually works: ... ~ '^ ....

Comment: `~`: [Difference between LIKE and ~ in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452395/difference-between-like-and-in-postgres), `^`: [Carets in Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944357/carets-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression in PostgreSQL LIKE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24368404/regular-expression-in-postgresql-like-clause)

Comment: To be honest, I see that they are relationed with my question.
But I can't understand because of the vocabulary that they use.
For this reason that I solicited practical examples, because many times is very diffcult to understand with this vocabulary and another expresssions that more experienced people use.

Comment: A quick primer. `~` is a regular expression match operator, it returns true if the left text operand matches the right regex operand. `'12345' ~ '23'` returns true, `'12345' ~ '24'` - false. `^` means two different things. If it is in the beginning of a regex then it means 'start of the string'. So `'12345' ~ '^23'` is false because the string does not start with '23'. If ^ is the first character of a range, `[^1-9A-F]`, it negates the range, i.e. everything *except* hex letters and digits.

Answer (score 5):

Let's simplify the query in your question to the component parts you're asking about. Once we see how they work individually, perhaps the whole query will make more sense.

---

To start, the `~` (tilde) is the [POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780599/what-is-the-meaning-of-posix), case-sensitive  [regular expression operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP). The linked PostgreSQL documentation provides brief descriptions and usage examples of it and its sibling operators:

| Operator | Description | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `~` | Matches regular expression, case sensitive | `'thomas' ~ '.*thomas.*'` |
| `~*` | Matches regular expression, case insensitive | `'thomas' ~* '.*Thomas.*'` |
| `!~` | Does not match regular expression, case sensitive | `'thomas' !~ '.*Thomas.*'` |
| `!~*` | Does not match regular expression, case insensitive | `'thomas' !~* '.*vadim.*'` |

We can see that each operator has two operands: a constant string on the left, and a pattern on the right. If the string on the left is a match for the pattern on the right, the statement is `true`, otherwise it is `false`.

In the given example for the operator you're asking about, `'thomas'` is a match for the pattern `'.*thomas.*'` by standard regular expression rules. The `'.*'` pre-and-postfixes mean "match [any character (except newline)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912894/how-to-match-any-character-in-regular-expression) any number of times ([zero or more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763820/difference-between-and-regex))". The whole pattern then means, "match any character any number of times, then the literal string 'thomas', then any character any number of times". One such match would be `'john thomas jones'` where `'john '` matches the first `'.*'` and `' jones'` matches the second `'.*'`.

I don't think this is a great example because it is functionally equivalent to `'thomas' LIKE '%thomas%'` which is likely to run faster, [among other benefits like being a SQL-standard operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12452518/14956277).

A better example is the query in your question where the pattern `'^[0-9]'` is used. Setting aside the `^` for now, this pattern means, "match any character in `0-9` (0, 1, 2, ..., 8, 9)", which would be much more verbose if you were to use the `LIKE` operator: `field LIKE '^0' OR field LIKE '^1' OR field LIKE '^2' ...`.

---

The `^` operator is not PostgreSQL-specific. Rather it is a special character in regular expressions with one of two meanings ([aside from its use as a literal character; more about that in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16944517/14956277)):

1. The match should begin at the start of the line/string.

> For example, the string "Hello, World!" *would* contain a match for the pattern `'World'` since the word "World" appears in it, but would not contain a match for the pattern `'^World'` since the word "World" is not at the start of the string.
>
> The string "Hello, World!" would contain a match for both of the following patterns: `'Hello'` and `'^Hello'` since the word "Hello" is at the start of the string.

2. The given character set should be negated when making a match.

> For example, the pattern `[^0-9]` means, "match any character that is not in the range 0-9". So `'a'` would match, `'&'` would match, and `'G'` would match, but `'7'` would not match since it is in the character set that is being excluded.

The query in your question uses the first of the two meanings. The pattern `'^[0-9]'` means, "match any character in the range 0-9 starting at the beginning of the string". So `'0123'` would match since the string starts with "0", but `'a5'` would not match since the string starts with "a" which is not the character set that is being matched.

---

Back to the query in your question, then. The relevant part reads:

```sql
1    count(distinct 
2        case 
3            when left(business_address, 1) ~ '^[0-9]' 
4                then lower(split_part(business_address, ' ', 2)) 
5            else lower(split_part(business_address, ' ', 1)) 
6        end 
7    ) as n_street
```

Line 3 contains a regular expression match that will determine if we should use this case in the overall `CASE` statement. If the string matches the pattern, the expression will be `true` and we will use this case. If the string does not match the pattern, the expression will be `false` and we will try the next case.

The string we are matching to the pattern is `left(business_address, 1)`. The [`LEFT` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) takes the first `n` characters from the string. Since `n` is "1" here, this returns the first character of the field `business_address`.

The pattern we are trying to match this string to is `'^[0-9]'` which we have already said means, "match any character in the range 0-9 starting at the beginning of the string". Technically we don't need the `^` regex operator here since `LEFT(..., 1)` will return at most one character (which will always be the first character in the resulting string).

As an example, if `business_address` is "123 Jones Street, Anytown, USA", then `LEFT(business_address, 1)` will return "1" which will match the pattern (and therefore the expression will be `true` and we will use the first case).

If, instead, `business_address` were "Jones Plaza, Suite 123, Anytown, USA", then `LEFT(business_address, 1)` would return "J" which would not match the pattern (since the first character is "J" which is not in the range 0-9). Our expression would be `false` and we would continue to the next case.