# SQL wildcard to fetch numbers only

Tags: sql, postgresql, wildcard

I have a query which is like this 
`select * from table_sports where player_id like 'playerId-%';`
Here there the player_id column can have values in this format  `playerId-123` or `playerId-12-32343` the number size after the hyphen (-) is unknown it can be `playerId-1000012` too.
 
 I just want to fetch the records having this format like this `playerId-123` and avoid records having this format `playerId-12-32343` (two hyphens) 
 
I have tried queries like these `select * from table_sports where player_id like 'playerId-[0-9]';`
,`select * from table_sports where player_id like 'playerId-%^/-';` That did not work (no records are returned), I googled it , but no luck with that. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE` doesn't support regular expressions in SQL.

You either need to use the standard compliant `similar to` or Postgres' proprietary `~` operator to compare against a regex.

```
where player_id similar to 'playerId-[0-9]+'

where player_id ~ '^playerId-[0-9]+$'
```

Note the difference in the regex: `similar to` doesn't need the "anchor" because it always does a full match.

If you want a case **in**sensitive comparison, use `~*` instead of `~`

Comment: Awesome that works like a charm!, also one question which way is the fastest in SQL is it similar to or regex?

Comment: @Deepakvelu: they should have the same performance (and neither will use an index on that column)

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE` doesn't work with regular expressions, you can use one of the below methods:

**Method 1:** Exclude not needed records with another `where` condition

```sql
select * from table_sports 
where player_id like 'playerId-%'
and player_id not like 'playerId-%-%';
```

---

**Method 2:** Use the [regular expression operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) `~` to use [bracket expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ATOMS-TABLE)

```sql
select * from table_sports 
where player_id ~ '^playerId-([0-9]+)$'
```

---

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24369117/8494462) to know why `LIKE` is faster than using `regular expressions` in this case. And why [you shouldn't use `SIMILAR TO`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452395/difference-between-like-and-in-postgres/12459689#12459689)