# How to use LIKE in these cases?

Tags: postgresql

There is a list of countries.
I want to get the list of the countries that:

1. consist of the letter U and A -or- S
2. consist of the letter U and any character except S.

These structures are correct for the MS SQL but don't work for Postgres

For MS SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    country
FROM world.country
WHERE country LIKE 'U[AS]%'

SELECT 
    country
FROM world.country
WHERE country LIKE 'U[S]%'
```

For Postgres?

Comment: May be this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24368404/regular-expression-in-postgresql-like-clause

Answer (score 0):

You can use SIMILAR TO  [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html)

```sql
select * from (values ('UAA'),('MUA'),('UUA'),('USA')) as test (country)
where country SIMILAR TO 'U(A|S)%'
```

returns 'UAA' and 'USA'

You can use also POSIX regular expression with the same result.

```sql
select * from (values ('UAA'),('MUA'),('UUA'),('USA')) as test (country)
where country ~ '^U(A|S)'
```