# SQL server adding where clause that doesn't affect results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query

```
  select count(person),  from [table]
  where (date > '2015-01-01')
  group by person
```

This query returns 100  as result, i need to know how to add another condition in where clause using `LIKE` and getting the same result  (100)

```
  select count(person),  from [table]
  where (date > '2015-01-01' and name LIKE '%?%')
  group by person
```

The name column event if it's added it should have no effect on the final result

Comment: That's a strange request. Assuming name is never NULL, changing the end to `'%'` should do it.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a search routine

Comment: Be careful with such patterns for writing generalised search queries *(where one query can full-fill many different criteria)*; it can totally hammer performance... http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is two way of doing this, but what is the meaning of this?

```
select count(person),  from [table]
where (date > '2015-01-01' and (name LIKE '%' or name is null))
group by person
```

Or:

```
select count(person),  from [table]
where (date > '2015-01-01' and (name LIKE '%sometext%' or 1 = 1))
group by person
```

Comment: Thats works, well i need it in my asp.net application i'm doing some checkings so i'm using it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the [`TOP` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)?

```
select TOP 100 count(person) As PersonCount, Person
from [table]
where (date > '2015-01-01' and name LIKE '%?%')
group by person
```

Comment: I need to get first 100 results, is their any drawback using it ?

Comment: No, the `?` has no special meaning in a `LIKE` as far as i know. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712580/list-of-special-characters-for-sql-like-clause

Comment: That's strange i'll try to find another solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select top 100 count(person),  from [table]
where (date > '2015-01-01' and name LIKE '%?%')
group by person
```

Assuming that there are more than 100 results for which `name` is containing `?` else the result will differ.

Comment: It gives 0 record in this case it searches for values matching '?'

Comment: @drexdrex:- Is your name field is containing the `?` ?

Comment: @drexdrex:- So how you are expecting the result to return a row?

Comment: Ooops i havent noticed it, coincidence i'm working on another query that contains TOP 100, i thought it's the one i posted. Well noticed !!