# How to search Special character (%) in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a record with a value `Jacj%25011987`. I wanted to search the record with `%` as a character in a string.

I wanted to search this record using the `Like` in `where` clause.

I tried these queries, but they didn't work:

```
Select * 
From Table1 With (Nolock) 
Where Column1 like '%\%%'

Select * 
From Table1 With (Nolock) 
Where Column1 like '%'%%'
```

Thanks
Parag

Comment: Here's [a link for reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/712580/4780877), covers others databases besides sql-server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use `[]`:

```
where column1 like '%[%]%'
```

You can also use `escape` with whatever you like for the escape character:

```
where column1 like '%!%%' escape '!'
```

This is more portable, because `ESCAPE` is part of the ANSI standard.

Comment: Thanks :) .
That worked in my requirement .