# SQL expression using regex difference between MSSQL and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, regex

I am executing the following query in both MSSQL and MySQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY LIKE '[aeiou]%'
```

It prints all the cities starting with a vowel in MSSQL, but no rows are printed when executed in MySQL (no error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only wildcard characters supported by MySQL `LIKE` are `%` (for any string) and `_` (for any single character). It doesn't support the MSSQL extension `[]` for character sets. If you need that, use a regular expression, not a wildcard.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY RLIKE '^[aeiou]'
```

See [List of special characters for SQL LIKE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712580/list-of-special-characters-for-sql-like-clause) for comparisons of `LIKE` between different SQL implementations.

Comment: [] is not an "MSSQL extension," it is called a CLOSURE.  Standard Markovian regular expression syntax (don't confuse with the UNIX shell version of []: rules for "globbing" metacharacters [so called because the expansion used to be done by a separate executable called /etc/glob] are different).  Whether MySQL implements that operator is another question.

Comment: @BruceDavidWilner I know what it is, but it's not part of ANSI SQL patterns. They copied it from regular expressions and added it to their patterns, that's what I mean by it being an extension.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL uses the REGEXP keyword for regular expressions, so you'll want something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[aeiou]'
```