# How many guests have made bookings in the month of March?

Tags: sql

How can I calculate the amount of numbers and only those from the date of march for instance (24/03/2016, 29/03/2016 etc.)

Comment: yes, you have to use an `AND` between those conditions

Comment: `WHERE Price < 200 AND Types LIKE '%D%';` should solve this for you.

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is wrongly phrased. It should be `WHERE Price <200 Types AND Like '%D%'` (note the `%` instead of `@`).

Comment: @FDavidov Not all RDBMS uses `%` as a wildcard . Most of them does, but not all of them.

Comment: Well, those I know do (ORACLE, MySQL, SQL-Server). And since not specific one was tagged, I selected the most common and standard (ANSI) syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things come to mind.  First, I haven't seen a product that uses the @ symbol... it is usually the % symbol.  Second you do need the AND keyword.

```
SELECT * FROM Room WHERE (Price < 200) AND (Types LIKE '%D%')
```

But that leads to the third thing.  This query is going to pull anything that has a 'D' *anywhere* in the types field.  If a new type is added later that happens to have a 'D' in the name you are going to suddenly get results you were not expecting.  You may want to be more explicit in your condition...

```
SELECT * FROM Room WHERE (Price < 200) AND (Types LIKE '%Double%')
```

Obviously if your product really does use the '@' character then substitute it instead.  For what its worth, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712580/list-of-special-characters-for-sql-like-clause) question that lists valid characters for several products and none of the products listed use @.

Comment: Thanks you guys !!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM Room
WHERE Price < 200
AND
Types LIKE '@D@'

I guess you were looking for the "AND" keyword.

Comment: Just for my information: What RDBMS uses @ as a wildcard?

Comment: Can't say I've seen it either.