# SQL Server 'LIKE' or varchar issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I have a stored procedure that searches a table on a column by a string I pass into a `varchar`.

This works, returns the specific record with the correct ING_LOC_DESCRIPTION

```
DECLARE @strSearch VARCHAR(500)
SET @strSearch = 'Care1st LETTER Location'

SELECT TOP 10 ING_LOC_DESCRIPTION
FROM [CDRS].[ING_LOC_TRANS_MASTER]
WHERE [ING_LOC_DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%' + @strSearch + '%'
ORDER BY [ING_LOC_ID]
```

This doesn't work returns the top ten results from all records ordered by `ING_LOC_ID`:

```
DECLARE @strSearch VARCHAR(500)
SET @strSearch = '[{"WorkFlowID":"MoveFile"}]'

SELECT TOP 10 ING_LOC_DESCRIPTION
FROM [CDRS].[ING_LOC_TRANS_MASTER]
WHERE [ING_LOC_DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%' + @strSearch + '%'
ORDER BY [ING_LOC_ID]
```

Are any of these characters [, {, ", :, }, ] invalid in a `varchar`? Is it being interpreted as 2 strings? Or is it a problem with the `LIKE` keyword?

The string assignment seems to be ok because

```
DECLARE @strSearch VARCHAR(500)
SET @strSearch = '[{"WorkFlowID":"MoveFile"}]'

SELECT @strSearch
```

returns

```
[{"WorkFlowID":"MoveFile"}]
```

Unfortunately

```
DECLARE @strSearch VARCHAR(500)
SET @strSearch = '[{"WorkFlowID":"MoveFile"}]'

SELECT @strSearch LIKE '[{"WorkFlowID":"MoveFile"}]'
```

Does not return true or false as I had hoped, it returns an error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'

I think `LIKE` can only be used in a `WHERE` clause so I don't think that proves a problem with using `LIKE`.

Comment: SQL Server supports the [bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603) data type. (Valid values are 0, 1, 'TRUE' and 'FALSE'.) There is a [boolean](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx#Anchor_0) data type (with values TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN), but you cannot get a firm grip on one: "Unlike other SQL Server data types, a Boolean data type cannot be specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and cannot be returned in a result set." You can use `case when @TestString like @Pattern then 1 else 0 end` to get a `0`/`1` value from a `like` test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  In a `LIKE`, the `[`/`]` bounds a character class.  So the code matches any value that contains `{` or `"` or `W` and so on.

I would recommend using a different method:

```
SELECT TOP 10 ING_LOC_DESCRIPTION
FROM [CDRS].[ING_LOC_TRANS_MASTER]
WHERE CHARINDEX(@strSearch, ING_LOC_DESCRIPTION) > 0
ORDER BY [ING_LOC_ID];
```

No wildcards in a simple string match.

Comment: Thanks guys I think you've nailed it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape special characters:

[List of special characters for SQL LIKE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712580/list-of-special-characters-for-sql-like-clause)

[Pattern Matching with the ESCAPE Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#pattern-matching-with-the-escape-clause)

Answer (score 1):

The `[` `]` chars has special meaning in T-Sql `LIKE` - They are used for pattern searches.

For instance: `WHERE column LIKE '[a-c]%'` will return all records where `column` starts with `a`, `b` or `c`, while `WHERE column LIKE '[^a-c]%'` will return all records where `Column` does not start with `a`, `b` or `c`.

You can escape the `[` char by wrapping it inside `[]`: `WHERE column LIKE '[[]a]%'` will return all records where column starts with `[a]` (no need to escape the closing bracket).

For more information, read about the [arguments of the `like` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments), and [Using Wildcard Characters As Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-wildcard-characters-as-literals) a little down the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Gordon's answer is probably the neatest way to do this, but here is an example using `ESCAPE`:

```
SELECT TOP 10 ING_LOC_DESCRIPTION
FROM [CDRS].[ING_LOC_TRANS_MASTER]
WHERE [ING_LOC_DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%'+@strSearch+'%' ESCAPE '['
```

You only need to escape one of the square brackets to avoid the brackets binding a character class.