# How to escape special characters from SQL LIKE clause?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, special-characters, sql-like

I'm using the guide at https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-rsql-fiql to build an RSQL based JPA specification.

The like clause looks like the following:

```
return builder.like(root.get(property), argument.toString().replace('*', '%'));
```

My question is, what is the best way to handle escaping special characters in the user's input?

For example, if the user supplied the string:

```
*my-search%-term*
```

the above code would translate this to:

```
%my-search%-term%
```

I would want to escape the `%` in the string so that it is not evaluated as the `%` wildcard in the LIKE clause.

The following post states the LIKE special characters for each database:

[List of special characters for SQL LIKE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712580/list-of-special-characters-for-sql-like-clause)

and also note this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/712738/12177456) from one of the answers:

> It's impossible to write DBMS-independent code here, because you don't
>   know what characters you're going to have to escape, and the standard
>   says you can't escape things that don't need to be escaped. (See
>   section 8.5/General Rules/3.a.ii.)

I am wondering what the best way to handle this is? I'm using postgres in production, and h2 in testing, but ideally don't want the solution tied to either of these.

Comment: The comment you quote is wrong. There are exactly two characters that require escaping `_` and `%`

Comment: "*I'm using postgres in production, and h2 in testing*" which itself is a bad idea because you can never be sure that your code works correctly in production

Answer (score 0):

Why not use regular expression matching instead of `like`?

```
where col ~ <user input>
```

It sounds like your users may be more familiar with regular expressions.

If you just want an exact match that ignores all wildcard functionality, you can use position:

```
where position(<user input> in col) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL you only need to escape the `%` and `_` characters as those are the only wildcards supported by the `LIKE` operator.

So `*my-search%-term*` should be used like this in SQL

```
WHERE some_column LIKE '%my-search\%-term%' escape '\'
```